# Java compilation error cannot find symbol in implementing interface

Tags: java, interface

The following error showed while I was compiling my Java class:

> Radius.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
>       public class Radius implements B,C
>                                      ^
>         symbol: class B
>       Radius.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
>       public class Radius implements B,C
>                                        ^
>         symbol: class C
>       2 errors

The Java class in question:

```
class A
{
    int radius;
    interface B
    {
        public String displayRadius();
    }

    interface C
    {
        public String displayArea();
    }

    public void displayRadius()
    {
        radius=2;
        System.out.println("Radius : "+radius);
    }

    public void displayArea()
    {
        double area;
        area=3.14*radius*radius;
        System.out.println("Area :"+area);
    }
}

public class Radius implements B,C
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A ob=new A();
        ob.displayRadius();
        ob.displayArea();
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Could you at least add some pieces of information ? Or at least introduce your problem ?

Comment: B and C are nested inside A, try to refer to them as A.B and A.C, next issue is with visibility A must be public if you want to use B and C in public class Radius

Answer (score 2):

The interfaces are not directly accessible, as they are nested in the class `A`. Use this instead:

```
public class Radius implements A.B, A.C
```

So the whole code becomes:

```
class Radius implements A.B, A.C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A ob = new A();
        ob.displayRadius();
        ob.displayArea();
    }

    @Override
    public String displayArea() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String displayRadius() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}

class A {
    int radius;

    interface B {
        public String displayRadius();
    }

    interface C {
        public String displayArea();
    }

    public void displayRadius() {
        radius = 2;
        System.out.println("Radius : " + radius);
    }

    public void displayArea() {
        double area;
        area = 3.14 * radius * radius;
        System.out.println("Area :" + area);
    }
}
```